# Problem with fwrite php

Tags: php, fwrite, fsockopen

I am getting problem while using fwrite in php. the following code works in my local computer but gives error in server.

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if(!$fp) {
   echo 'Error: '.$errno.', '.$errstr;
} else {
   fwrite($fp, 'kool');
}
```

There is no error with fsockopen. it passes and gives no error. fwrite is not being able to write. it fails and returns no error only false

Comment: What's the error that it's giving you?

Comment: no errors in fsockopen. its giving error in fwrite. and its blank

Comment: Are you sure fwrite is returning FALSE?... Writing 'kool' to a webserver should not work anyway. You might also want to check the return value of stream_get_meta_data.

Comment: What does it return on your local machine?

Comment: in local machine its working fine. I am getting the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a shared host, most likely your server does not allow outbound connections on port 80. Usually only inbound connections are allowed.

Comment: may be you are right. I am using shared host. So what can be the alternative for me?

Comment: If you're with a larger company (BlueHost, Aplus, GoDaddy, etc) you should be able to ask their tech support to have outbound port 80 opened for you. It's a common request, they just have it turned off by default for security reasons.

Comment: is there any alternatives of this method?

Comment: That really depends on the problem you're trying to solve. If the only solution involves creating an outbound connection on a blocked port, and your host will not open that port for outbound connections, then there's not much you can do except change hosts.

Answer (score 3):

This is a permissions issue with the Apache/Nobody user accessing a remote file that it doesn't have permission to modify/read/write/execute.

You should also print the error message(s) for debugging

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if(!$fp) {
    echo "Error No: ".$errno."<br />\n";
    echo "Error Str: ".$errstr."<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, 'kool');
}
```

Comment: no errors in fsockopen. its giving error in fwrite. and its blank